# How to change Launch Screen File to Launch Images Source when app update?

Tags: ios, launchimage

In my app v1.0,I use Launch Screen File to dispaly my Launch Image,but in v2.0,we changed it to Launch Images source

but,when we update our app from v1.0 to v2.0,the launch image is still the original one, how to deal with it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: have u added all splash in launchimages assets?

Answer (score 1):

I test it ,it seems the only way to update your launchImage is unistall the app ,and install again.

I think this is apple's bug , Apple cache the snapshots,but don't update it when we change the setting.